# google places returns few results for germany

Tags: google-maps, web-applications, google-places-api

We're using the Google Map and Google Places API on a web application for travellers. we noticed that in GERMANY the API returns only a tiny fraction of the results that you would expect (and that you can find on a websearch on maps.google.com). E.g. the API returns only 6 results for a search for place type 'cafe' and a radius of 5km for 'Berlin'. We don't experience this issue with any non-German locations, but we can reproduce this for all German cities we tested. We also see this issue for other place types (e.g. 'bar' place type returns 4 results in Hamburg!!! [1]) 
The same search in Madrid returns countless results and you can load more and more [2].

What could be causing this? Is there a bug or is this a privacy issue of some sort? 
I searched high and low on the web, but found no reference to anything similar.

Our app is in development, but you can see a preview at dev.mygap.com

Thanks
Anne

(oh shoot - I would attach images to clarify but I need 10 reputation...)

Comment: I have the same problem, searching for restaurants in cologne (I copied the coordinates from a direct google map search), I only get very few results.   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=MY_KEY&sensor=false&radius=50000&location=50.9344595,6.9476285&query=restaurant . Did you manage to resolve your problem?

Comment: Not yet, Andreas. Pls vote the topic up and maybe some other folks can chime in who have a solution?

Comment: I did. Also, I think this is it: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7498 . Took 6 weeks to acknowledge.